# mobile version doesn't appear on iphone

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design, viewport

I'm developing a website which has a full version and a mobile version.

and I'm using this code to set the viewport meta tag:

```
<meta id="viewport" name="viewport" content="width=1100, maximum-scale=1.0" />
<script>
        deviceWidth = window.innerWidth;
        var viewport = document.getElementById('viewport');
        if(deviceWidth <= 480) viewport.setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0');
</script>
```

So the default meta is set to `content-width = 1100` and if this device-width is smaller than 480px it is set to `'width=device-width`.

It works well on all android phones, but doesn't work on iphone.

What is the problem and how can I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

To match your flexible layout width to the device width , you can use this one:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This works for Android, Iphone and Browsers. No need to change the content from the meta tag to detect what is the device/browser width.

Learn more about meta tags [here](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/articles/quick-tip-dont-forget-the-viewport-meta-tag--webdesign-5972).

Comment: Thanks, but the reason of using this is I want to show the website zoomed out and have a 50px margin of both sides on the tablets.